# A circuit that outputs one input voltage by default, or another if it is present

Tags: multiplexer

I'm trying to come up with a simple design that will take two analog inputs voltages (~0.2-1.6 V each). One is an "internal" voltage and should always be present. The second "external" input can be present, or can be not connected, floating, etc.

The circuit should output the external voltage if it is present, and the internal one otherwise.

The simplest idea I can think of is to have a comparator on the external line, which should output a logic high when the voltage raises sufficiently above ground, and use that to control an analog multiplexer. But I was hoping for a simpler idea.

The context [linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-duE2udUkU) here, an external controller port for a Nintendo 3DS. The internal voltage is from the circle pad, and the external controller should override this when it is connected. So, there are also two axes, so I could duplicate the circuit twice or find a more elegant method. And it has to fit inside the console.

Comment: So... an And Gate? Maybe an Or gate?

Comment: Heck, a series resistor on the line to be overriden, with a direct connection on the line that should take presidence.

Answer (score 1):

You could just connect the "internal" voltage to the same node as the "external" input via a high value resistor.

If the input is open-circuit, that node 'A' will take the voltage of the internal voltage source.  If the input is connected, unless its impedance is very high then node A will assume the voltage of the input.

An op amp configured as a voltage follower (unity-gain buffer) takes the result, isolates it from whatever you're connecting the output to and presents a low-impedance source to the output.  If the load is sufficiently high-impedance, the buffer could be omitted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdVRjp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This would probably work and it's making me feel stupid. The output is _probably_ high impedance, because the internal voltage comes from a potentiometer/voltage divider, and must go to one of the ICs on the board to be read in. It's not really driving anything.